# Cannot get exit code from git diff for files

Tags: git, powershell, cmd

Is it possible to use `git diff` to compare two files outside of the repo? If so, why is the exit code not zero (0) when there is a difference between the files? What am I missing?

In cmd.exe:

```
 9:43:55.45 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>TYPE .\t1.txt
this is t1.txt

 9:43:57.92 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>TYPE .\t2.txt
this is t2.txt

 9:43:57.94 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t1.txt

 9:43:58.04 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
0

 9:43:58.04 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t2.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

 9:43:58.14 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

In PowerShell 7.3.6:

```
PS C:\src\t\scripts> Get-Content -Path .\t1.txt
this is t1.txt
PS C:\src\t\scripts> Get-Content -Path  .\t2.txt
this is t2.txt
PS C:\src\t\scripts> & 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t1.txt
PS C:\src\t\scripts> $LASTEXITCODE
0
PS C:\src\t\scripts> & 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t2.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
PS C:\src\t\scripts> $LASTEXITCODE
0
PS C:\src\t\scripts> & 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t1.txt
PS C:\src\t\scripts> $?
True
PS C:\src\t\scripts> & 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' diff --exit-code --no-index  --ignore-all-space  --shortstat  .\t1.txt .\t2.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
PS C:\src\t\scripts> $?
True
```

I am using:

```
PS C:\src\t\scripts> git --version
git version 2.39.2.windows.1
```

From the git-diff man page at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

```
--exit-code
Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is,
it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.
```

Yes, `git` can set a non-zero exit code and returning in cmd.exe and pwsh.exe. Testing `git` setting the exit code to non-zero in cmd.exe.

```
 9:54:45.54 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>TYPE testgit.bat
@"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" >NUL
@ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
 9:54:56.14 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>CALL testgit.bat
1

 9:54:58.82 2023-08-04  C:\src\t\scripts>testgit.bat
1
```

Testing `git` setting the exit code to non-zero in pwsh.exe.

```
PS C:\src\t\scripts> Get-Content -Path  .\testgit.ps1
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' | Out-Null
$LASTEXITCODE
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' | Out-Null
$?
PS C:\src\t\scripts> .\testgit.ps1
1
False
```

There is only one (1) `git` on the system.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command git -All

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     git.exe                                            2.39.2.1   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: Exit code just indicates the app complete and returned 0 when successful.  It doesn't give the comparison of the files.  You need to parse the string output to determine the results.

Comment: @jdweng, I added the documentation on git-diff --exit-code to the question. Does this not suggest that the exit code should be 1 if there are differences?

Comment: @lit: It does, and I cannot reproduce your symptom. Perhaps `git` is a _function or script_ wrapper around the actual `git.exe`, and whatever happens in the wrapper resets `$LASTEXITCODE`? What does `Get-Command git -all` indicate?

Comment: Windows has Standard Output and Error Output.  The difference is Standard Output which is not the Exit Code.  Powershell has different output types : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng, please consider deleting your comments here. They are confusing distractions, in no way relevant to this question.

Comment: I have replaced `git` invocations with a fully qualified path to the `git` executable. No wrappers.

Comment: Is there something in your `prompt` function or some other hook that could be resetting `$LASTEXITCODE`? What happens if you provoke an error by just running `git`, which sets the exit code to `1`? is `$LASTEXITCODE` then still `0` when queried interactively at the next prompt? Do you also see the problem if you place both the `git` call and subsequently outputting `$LASTEXITCODE` _in a script_ and execute the latter?

Comment: @mklement0, yes, `git` will set a non-zero exit code and return it in both cmd.exe and pwsh.exe. Example added to the question.

Comment: I also put the original cmd and pwsh statements into script files. They produce the same results as at an interactive prompt. I can paste the results into the question if requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that only shows up for me when combining `--ignore-all-space` and kin with summary stats (`--shortstat` and kin), as a workaround add `--quiet` and you'll get the return code (but no other output, if you really need the ignore-all-space shortstat output and the return code you'll need two runs).

Comment: Many thanks, @jthill. What I really want is "ignore line endings". Is there a switch other than `--ignore-all-space` that will do that?

Comment: `--ignore-cr-at-eol` does the whitespace processing you want but unfortunately has the same annoying bug combining output and return code.